# Word 2010 Appearance in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-word

I installed Word 2010 from a legitimate source using my own product key, however there seems to be an issue with the appearance. There's some sort of weird box over the drop down menu and the shadow on the page is not how it is supposed to look. Does anyone have any ideas? Please drag image into browser bar in order to enlarge.

[image]

Comment: I tried other office products and I am having the same issue. Please help.

Comment: Border I can see, but what weird box?

Comment: Any ideas Karan? The box is in the topleft corner over the file menu.

Comment: Now I see it. Are your graphics drivers updated? Does messing with [visual effects](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5657-visual-effects-adjust-windows-8-a.html) make any difference at all? Also, according to reports this bug affects only 64-bit Office 2010, so if you have no specific need for it you might want to try the 32-bit version instead if you have access to it.

Comment: I have a state of the art laptop with Intel HD graphics 4000 and NVidia GeForce GTX.

Comment: State of the art has nothing to do with how updated or not your drivers are. Also, does switching between the graphics solutions help?

Comment: Let me give a try. I'll get back to you in a minute.

Comment: Click on the weird box. It gives you some options like minimize/maximize, close, etc. On my system the box has a big 'W' inside. I guess that stands for 'Word'.

Comment: @Karan I tried it but got nothing. My drivers were completely up to date.

Comment: @whu I am not getting those options at all.

Comment: I suppose the only option might be to try 32-bit Office if you have the 64-bit version installed. Or else keep using this if it's not a major issue.

Comment: I'd really like to get rid of it. Are there any other options? Do you know why this is even happening?

Comment: From what I read it's a graphics glitch that occurs only with the 64-bit version in combination with certain drivers. No sure how accurate that information is though. Again, if Office 32-bit looks ok then that will confirm what I've found about this issue so far.

Comment: Would I need to purchase a different installation? I only have the 64 bit.

Comment: Just use the same key but the 32-bit installer